# PHP: how to directly convert xpath to node/attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes

I wonder if in PHP there is a direct way (without iterations) to convert xpath, say:

```
component_volume_concentration/component[1][@formula="CH4"]
component_volume_concentration/component[1][@unit="%"]
component_volume_concentration/component[1][@min="22"]
component_volume_concentration/component[1][@norm="25"]
component_volume_concentration/component[1][@max="30"]
```

to XML node and attribute structure:

```
<component_volume_concentration> 
<component formula="CH4" unit="%" min="22" norm="25" max="30" />
<component formula="C2H6" unit="%" min="22" norm="25" max="30" />
<component formula="C3H8" unit="%" min="22" norm="25" max="30" />
<component formula="i-C4H10" unit="%" min="22" norm="25" max="30" />
<component formula="i-C5H12" unit="%" min="22" norm="25" max="30" />
</component_volume_concentration>
```

Thank you!

Comment: No idea, but it seems pretty easy to write yourself?

Answer (score 1):

No, use [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/) or [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation).

Xpath is a query language to select nodes. It is used in XSLT and is a subset of XQuery.

It is not possible to expand all Xpath expressions to valid nodes.

How would you expand something like `.//component[@formula="CH4"][last()]` or `count(//node[@attr]) > 0`.

You can define an own Xpath like syntax and develop an interpreter for it. But this would be a lot of work and you need a really good knowledge of XML (namespaces, node types, whitespace handling, cdata sections).